# Upload to S3 database config in JS

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, credentials

I'm quite new at AWS, so what I am doing is probably very wrong. I'm working on an app which uses an S3 bucket for data storage. The users will have no access to this, so there is no need for user authentification. I just want to send a file from my code to the server. I use the following code to attempt this, but I cannot escape credential errors. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
var bucketName = 'my-bucket-name';
    var bucketRegion = 'us-west-2';
    function send(){

      var bucket = new AWS.S3({
          params: {
              Bucket: bucketName
          }
      });

      AWS.config.update({
        region: bucketRegion,
        accessKeyId: "my-access-key",
        secretAccessKey: "my-secret-key"
        //credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        //  IdentityPoolId: poolID
        //})
      });

      var timestamp = new Date().getTime()/1000;
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
      var data = canvas.toDataURL();
      if (data) {
            //Object key will be facebook-USERID#/FILE_NAME
            var objKey = "test-"+timestamp;
            var params = {
                Key: objKey,
                ContentType: data.type,
                Body: data,
                ACL: 'public-read'
            };
          bucket.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
              if (err) {
                  console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
              } else {
                  listObjs();
              }
          });
      } else {
          console.log('Nothing to upload.');
      }
  }
```

edit: the exact text of the error I get:

ERROR: CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config

Answer (score 0):

If your code is being hosted in Lambda, it's possible that you haven't set up a policy that allows the two services to speak to each other.

I would look into managing these policies here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_manage.html